# Getting results from results

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I apologize if I don't make much sense but I've tangled my brain up trying to work this out.

I'm trying to obtain a result set using the results from one query but then also hoping to include the previous results within the new query and then somehow group them.

What I have are parent Work order numbers and it’s child work order numbers.
Sadly the system I am using doesn't have the functionality set up yet to simply produce a report that shows all the specific type of work and their linked work.

So I have an initial basic query 1 to find anything that has a `"JPNUM like AK0147"` and `"STATUS NOT IN ('COMPLETE', 'CANCELLED', 'REVIEWED', 'CLOSED')"`

The result of the above query 1 will return a result set that includes the column 'WONUM'.
I need to then do a separate search using the column 'PARENT' whereby I return any results that have a number in this column matching any of the WONUMs that were returned in query 1.

I also want to include the results of query 1, probably in query 3, so I can group them together.
How do create write a query that includes my results from query 1 into query 2 and then how do I group them so I have the parent WONUM at the top and it's children work orders underneath, like the final results table I have shown in the attached image?

[image: Basic Query examples]

Comment: I really don't follow what you are *really* asking here. There isn't actually a question in the above. *If* I am understanding correctly, if you want to use the results of a prior query in a latter one, you need to `INSERT` said result set into a table (such as a temporary table), and then refer to that object in your latter statement. Otherwise [edit] your "question" and actually ask a question, you haven't here; just giving some kind of problem statement with no clear requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a `select` from another `select` and so on.

I will write you an example:

```
SELECT WONUM, PARENT.WONUM
  FROM (SELECT WONUM, JPNUM
          FROM yourTable
         WHERE "JPNUM like AK0147" 
           AND "STATUS NOT IN ('COMPLETE', 'CANCELLED', 'REVIEWED', 'CLOSED')") PARENT
 WHERE ...
```

This way the result of the inner `SELECT` acts like a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to do it, if you're using sql-server, I recommend CTE:

```
WITH Query1
(
    SELECT  WONUM, JPNUM
    FROM    MyTable1
    WHERE   ...
),

Query2
(
    SELECT  WONUM, PARENT
    FROM    Query1        -- You can use Query1, if you want
    JOIN    MyTable2    ON Query1.JPNUM = ...
    WHERE   ...
)

-- Final Result:
SELECT  WONUM, PARENT
FROM    Query2
JOIN    Query1    ON ...
JOIN    Table3    ON ...
WHERE   ...
```

In this way, you can query using previous query or previous previous query (if needed).